# Property file not found on classpath

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

My application.properties is located just in the same directory as my jar file.

However, the typesafe config does not find my properties...

I start my application with

```
java -cp "/home/testApp/*" example.Server
```

The .jar file is found, the application.properties not - although they are in the same directory!?

Comment: I don't get it. Where is your `application.properties` inside your sources structure?

Comment: How are you packaging your application? Why do you need a property file in the first place when you could do the same with a typesafe config file?